# How to parse json string in ajax?

Tags: ajax, json, cordova

I have response like this how to parse this data ? any suggestions

> {"response":[{"job_id":"29","message":"egfn","lattitude":"26.9514731","longitude":"89.4524783","job_status":"P","date":"2013-11-21
>   03:33:34","username":"users"},{"job_id":"28","message":"egfn","lattitude":"26.9514731","longitude":"89.4524783","job_status":"P","date":"2013-11-21
>   03:33:34","username":"rajeev"},{"job_id":"27","message":"egfn","lattitude":"26.9514731","longitude":"89.4524783","job_status":"P","date":"2013-11-21
>   03:33:34","username":"pankaj"},{"job_id":"26","message":"test job for
>   you","lattitude":"25.4558641","longitude":"80.1325838","job_status":"P","date":"2013-11-21
>   01:09:58","username":"users"},{"job_id":"24","message":"test job for
>   you","lattitude":"25.4558641","longitude":"80.1325838","job_status":"D","date":"2013-11-21
>   01:09:58","username":"amit"},{"job_id":"25","message":"test job for
>   you","lattitude":"25.4558641","longitude":"80.1325838","job_status":"P","date":"2013-11-21
>   01:09:58","username":"test"}]}

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seriously ? Ever heard of Google ? Googling your question's title sends back a lot of very good results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
JSON.parse('{"response":[{"job_id":"29","message":"egfn","lattitude":"26.9514731","longitude":"89.4524783","job_status":"P","date":"2013-11-21 03:33:34","username":"users"},{"job_id":"28","message":"egfn","lattitude":"26.9514731","longitude":"89.4524783","job_status":"P","date":"2013-11-21 03:33:34","username":"rajeev"},{"job_id":"27","message":"egfn","lattitude":"26.9514731","longitude":"89.4524783","job_status":"P","date":"2013-11-21 03:33:34","username":"pankaj"},{"job_id":"26","message":"test job for you","lattitude":"25.4558641","longitude":"80.1325838","job_status":"P","date":"2013-11-21 01:09:58","username":"users"},{"job_id":"24","message":"test job for you","lattitude":"25.4558641","longitude":"80.1325838","job_status":"D","date":"2013-11-21 01:09:58","username":"amit"},{"job_id":"25","message":"test job for you","lattitude":"25.4558641","longitude":"80.1325838","job_status":"P","date":"2013-11-21 01:09:58","username":"test"}]}')
```

EDIT:

to get all job_id do this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"response":[{"job_id":"29","message":"egfn","lattitude":"26.9514731","longitude":"89.4524783","job_status":"P","date":"2013-11-21 03:33:34","username":"users"},{"job_id":"28","message":"egfn","lattitude":"26.9514731","longitude":"89.4524783","job_status":"P","date":"2013-11-21 03:33:34","username":"rajeev"},{"job_id":"27","message":"egfn","lattitude":"26.9514731","longitude":"89.4524783","job_status":"P","date":"2013-11-21 03:33:34","username":"pankaj"},{"job_id":"26","message":"test job for you","lattitude":"25.4558641","longitude":"80.1325838","job_status":"P","date":"2013-11-21 01:09:58","username":"users"},{"job_id":"24","message":"test job for you","lattitude":"25.4558641","longitude":"80.1325838","job_status":"D","date":"2013-11-21 01:09:58","username":"amit"},{"job_id":"25","message":"test job for you","lattitude":"25.4558641","longitude":"80.1325838","job_status":"P","date":"2013-11-21 01:09:58","username":"test"}]}')

var job_id_array = new Array();

for(var i = 0;i< obj.response.length ; i++){
    job_id_array.push(obj.response[i].job_id);
}
```

Comment: i want to get all job_id please provide code thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery.parseJSON()

More details : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 1):

If your JSON string would be stored in the `json` variable, you may do the follwoing (given that the environment supports ECMAScript5):

```
var o =  JSON.parse(json);
var result=[];
o.response.forEach(function(e){
    result.push(e.job_id);
});
console.log(result);
```

which outputs the content of the `result` array:

```
["29", "28", "27", "26", "24", "25"]
```

Here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x8kv4/) and a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/674700) which addresses your question.